# powerpoint compatibility

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, compatibility

Imagine you work in Office 2007 or 2010, you create a far-fetched presentation and save it as 'ppt'. Office 2007/2010 warns you that some effects will be lost, but you save it.

Question: If you open that ppt file in the office version you're working with(2007/2010) will it run like on '97 or '03 with the lack of effects, no other problems?

I'm asking so I know whether I have to install an older office so I can check compatibility.I use 2010.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When opening an older version of an office document (e.g. .doc instead of .docx, .ppt instead of .pptx), the office program runs in compatibility mode. Effects that do not exist in the older version will not be available. This means you'll have a pretty accurate compatibility check.